# Create directory on server from within the android app

Tags: php, android, sudo, mkdir

How can I execute my php file which contains`mkdir` command from my android app? I tried giving root permission to my php file using `visudo` by following [this](http://www.bonebrews.com/granting-sudo-to-php/) link, but it still does not work.

However if I execute the php file from my terminal the directory gets created. So what do I need to do to make my android app execute this php file? Any idea ?

Below is my php file:

```
<?php
   $filename = $_POST['filename'];
   mkdir("./xyz/".$filename);
?>
```

And my Android Code for executing my php file (the core code):

```
 if(method == "POST"){
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
      is = httpEntity.getContent();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. File Needs 777 permission
2. Right Click on  any folder and say permission in ftp [set 777]

   progratically in php:

   ```
   if (!file_exists('path/my_file')) {
       mkdir('path/my_file, 0777, true);
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer but it still does not create any file

Comment: no when i right clicked on the folder and clicked on properties/permission tab i dint find ftp option any where.